# Android prevent intent restoration after Destroy on back button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, destroy

I'm running into an unpleasant issue I don't know how to solve properly.

Scenario:

MainActivity has a method handleIncomingIntent()

This method parses the Extras coming in the incoming intent (for service, or broadcast receiver) and opens Child Activities based on an intent data.
So, when the incoming Intent has data of type A it will startActivity(ActivityA.class), if of type B then startActivity(ActivityB.class) if no data it will stay in MainActivity

Problem is when device is low on memory, MainActivity is destroyed, while in ActivityA or ActivityB.

Therefore when BackButton is used - the MainActivity gets restored and it's incoming Intent is restored at the same state as before handling it despite the fact I'm doing incomingIntent.removeExtras(KEY) in the end of my handleIncomingIntent() method. So the outcome is - it's starting the Child Activity once again and it's a loop!

I realize that I can store some isIntentConsumed flag into memory inside onDestroy() and then read it restoreSavedState() and use it to dismiss the intent since it's already consumed.

I just feel there must be a better way than a "bandaid" that I just described.

Kind Regards, 
Pavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stopped Activity is destroyed due to system constraints other than normal conditions(user presses back or activity finish itself), the method **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)** will be called. When user navigates back to this kind of activity, **onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)** will be called and the previous saved bundle will be passed as parameter to both **onRestoreInstanceState()** and **onCreate()**.

So you can check the actual parameter of **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)**, if `savedInstanceState != null` you can know the activity is recreated. Hope helped.

Comment: Thanks Terry, I gonna try it tonight and will up-vote if that works.

Comment: Wow that was so simple. I didn't think about that. Thank you Terry. This is a correct answer

Comment: @PavelKirillov :) cheer, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by

> Problem is when device is low on memory, MainActivity is destroyed,
>   while in ActivityA or ActivityB.
>   it is not clear and also
>
> Therefore when Back Button is used

I think that you are talking about the back button press event on the Activity A or B if this is the case , I would suggest you to finish the MainActivity after moving to A or B activity . then on A/B activity , you should over ride the onBackPressed() method , you should start the main activity again and finish activity A/B.

doing this would save device from low memory. BTW did you tried it on real device also?  if not then check it on real device and let us know. I hope it would work for you

Comment: Thanks for replying ghost, yes. On a real device there is a developer option called destroy inactive activities. When selected, as soon as activity A/B is fully covering my Main Activity, the OS destroys the latter. But as you guessed it right, when I click the back button on A/B the Main is recreated. However the Intent that opened Main is restored to an original state, as if it's a first time.

Comment: I don't think it's better pattern to finish Main and re-create it from A/B because A/B can be opened by other callers, like C or D... So I will end up passing the caller to child and managing all kind of scenarios in on Back Button instead of finishing A/B and getting where it came from. Maybe there is a nice way of preventing Android to recreate the Intent to its unchanged state. My work around works, it just feels not right to me. I added a generation timestamp millis to intent and I save it to shared preferences to later see if I consumed it or not and ignore if needed.

Comment: I think it is kind of Diamond problem :) , but hope you will soon improve your coding and get satisfy yourself